# Displaying profile_name from friends table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to display the profile name of a user's friend. I have a friends table (users table) and the myfriends table (friend table). Don't ask why the stupidly confusing names, it is what the assignment requires. Ill refer as the friendsID as user_id and myfriendsID as friends_ID just to eliminate confusion.

Now, so far I have got it to list the user_id and the friends associated with that ID. 
I want it to be able to also display the friends names through a profile_name I have on the user_id table.

The SQL i have at the moment is:

```
    SELECT friends.friend_id, myfriends.friend_id2, friends.profile_name
    FROM friends 
    INNER JOIN myfriends 
    ON friends.friend_id = myfriends.friend_id1
    WHERE friends.friend_id = '2'
```

Problem is, is that it lists the name of the USER_ID, not the friend_id. The profile names I am trying to obtain are also from the user_id table, but with their own unique user_id. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join back to friends/users again.

```
Inner join friends as f2
On f2.friend_id = myfriends.friend_id1
```

Comment: Still showing the friend_id's name not the friend_id2

Comment: Update your select statement to use the alias f2. So call f2.whatever to get that column from the friends table to show